Convert HEIC image into JPEG in LWC
The task that would be trivial on any JS runtime that supports nmp turned out to be a little bit more challenging on the SF platform.
If an end user uploads a photo from their Apple device (image/heic), how to convert it to JPEG for further processing?
The heic2any package returns an undefined error when loaded from a static resource (I suspect because it uses eval()).
The heic-convert package uses WebAssembly by default which is not supported in LWC as far as I'm aware. Generates an error on an attempt to use it after loading from a static resource.

The sollution I came up with was to upload the pure JS version of libheif and use that in the code copied from heic-decode as a dependency replacing the wasm version.
So here's the code packaged as an LWC

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

....plus you appear to be the author of said repo - a disclaimer/disclosure that you're linking to your own code is recommended etiquette.

@identigral thanks for the input, amended my answer
